# Use value from array as property

Tags: javascript

So I have a dictionary-like object and an array:

```
var colors = {"b":color(0, 0, 0)};
var ar=[["b","0","0"],["b","b","0"],["b","b","b"]];
```

Now, I would like to get the value from the dictionary using the array like so:

```
colors.ar[0][0]
```

Which should give me the color black. However, this gives me an error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I believe this is because it's trying to access colors."b" instead of colors.b .

So how can I get the property from the dictionary by using a value from the array?

Thanks!

Comment: [JavaScript Square Bracket Notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it. What you want is this:

`colors[ar[0][0]]`

Since `ar[0][0]` resolves to `"b"`, `colors[ar[0][0]]` resolves to `colors["b"]`.

If you use dot notation it will try to access `colors.ar` which is undefined.